# How to track clicks of ads in email using google analytics?

Tags: php, javascript, google-analytics

I have this problem and really don't know how to solve this.

I'm having this newsletter using phplist system and I have to include some ads in emails. Now that's all fine but my client wants to track the number of clicks on those ads using google analytics.

Is there any way to do that? Thanks in advance for any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to do that?

Definitely not inside the E-Mail: No sane E-Mail client supports Javascript.

You would have to link the ads to a URL on your server, register the hit there using GA's [`_trackPageview()`](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._trackPageview) (or maybe [`_trackEvent()`](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html)), and redirect to the target ad.

Comment: Yeah, that's a tricky one. But thanks for pointing me into the right direction. Perhaps I'll figure out something from that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use the campaign Option from GA if you can include it in your Newsletter System, see http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/topic.py?hl=en&topic=10996

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that you can't really do it right away because you can't include JS in an email.

However you could maybe set up some kind of proxy between the ads and their links. When the user clicks a link it first redirects to a page with google analytics on it (probably on your servers) and then redirect to the actual link.

*Also I think some services provide an integrated stats system.*